# Dynamic Gridview Template and Unique Control (ie textbox, label) IDs?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield, unique-id

When creating a Gridview at design time you can create a template column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And in the HTML it will give it a unique name like:

```
<span id="gvSelect_ctl02_Label1">blahblah</span>
```

And I can then reference this label in the code behind by:

```
CType(e.Row.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
```

Which is PERFECT.  But I can't figure out how to do this when I'm creating TemplateFields Dynamically.  I've got the following code in my "InstantiateIn":

```
Dim hl As New HiddenField
hl.ID = "hHidden"
hl.Value = 0
AddHandler hl.DataBinding, AddressOf Me.hl_DataBinding
container.Controls.Add(hl)
```

And this DOES create a hidden control with the ID as hHidden in each row.  But it doesn't give it the unique ID like "gvSelect_ctl02_hHidden"  it's just "hHidden".  And I know there are ways to append the row number to it myself.  But I was wondering if there was a way for it to do this automatically.  And still allowing me to reference the hiddenfield like:

```
CType(e.Row.FindControl("hHidden"), HiddenField)
```

Comment: What is "container" in your example?

Comment: umm.. ByVal container As System.Web.UI.Control ?  Which is a "TemplateField"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.. another answer to my own question.  I was looking for the name in the RowCreated.  I should have been looking for it in the RowDataBound event.

it works now.. now that I'm doing it correctly.

(I may have too many things on the go at once..)  :S